Contiguous generalized hypergeometric functions modifying only denominator variables
The standard contiguous relations for the Gaussian Hypergeometric Functions
can be stacked/repeated to relate $_2F_1(a,b;c;z)$ in many ways
to sums of the formats $_2F_1(a\pm,b\pm ; c\pm ;z)$ , see e.g.
https://doi.org/10.4134/CKMS.2009.24.2.291
or https://doi.org/10.1016/j.camwa.2010.12.008 .
For $_3F_2$ and unit argument, contiguous relations of that type
are in https://doi.org/10.1017/S2040618500033049 , and for $_pF_q$
and general argument $z$ contiguous relations have been published
in https://doi.org/10.1088/0305-4470/21/9/015 and https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1945-08425-0 .
My question is: is there a 3-term relation that allows to write $_pF_q(...; ..b_i,...b_j,..;z)$
as a superposition of $_pF_q(...; ..b_i+1,...b_j-1,..;z)$
and $_pF_q(...; ..b_i+2,...b_j-2,..;z)$, which means, shifting pairs
of "denominators"  without modifying the "numerators"?
